(kdb+/q) issues with .u.rep in r.q
r.q - args for .u.rep
q)(hopen `$":",.u.x 0)"(.u.sub[`;`];`.u `i`L)"
,(`pace;+`time`sym`date`pt`pn`ph`pd`pc`pa..
(5487;`:tplog/tplog2024.06.04)
q)

When I remove the . before the args I get no error and the data comes into the rdb but it only shows the data from when I initiated the rdb processes as opposed to getting all the data since the feed started.
If I add the . back then I get a type error.
q).u.rep .(hopen `$":",.u.x 0)"(.u.sub[`;`];`.u `i`L)"
'type
  [1]  /Users/user/hb/ht/tp/r.q:16: .u.rep:{(.[;();:;].)each x;if[null first y;:()];-11!y;system "cd ",1_-10_string first reverse y}

Why is this?
UPDATE:
The args seem to be throwing up the type error.
q)(.[;();:;].)each first (hopen `$":",.u.x 0)"(.u.sub[`;`];`.u `i`L)"
,`pace
q)'type
'type
'type
'type
'type
'type
'type

The data types in my table schema
!(`timespan$();`g#`symbol$();`date$();"";`symbol$();`symbol$();"";`symbol$();`symbol$();"";`float$();`float$();`symbol$();"";"";"";`float$();"";"";`int$();`float$();"";"";"";"";`symbol$();`symbol$();`symbol$();`long$();`float$()))

Could the "" representing char type be the issue?

Use \e 1 to help you debug. For a C column the empty list is (). "" is for a c column.

@rianoc doesn't help - ```q)\e 1
q)(.[;();:;].)first first (hopen $":",.u.x 0)"(.u.sub[;];.u iL)"
`rprace
q)'type
'type
'type
'type
'type
'type
'type


@rianoc I think the issue is because I am using code that worked for multiple tables but I only have one table - just not sure how to resolve it

The schema you posted doesn't seem to be correct, how did you get this line of code? The .u.rep function should work for any number of tables. Can you inspect the arguments returned by the subscription? Store it in a variable and then inspect them.

Why isn't the schema correct? I obtained that from the x value for .u.rep. I also tested the issue with a working trade, quote tick.q system and it worked fine then I removed one of the tables and now the same issue happens. So there is an issue with it just being one table. I am getting a type error when trying to run -11!y - for some reason this is returning a type error.

the y value throwing the type error1508 `:tplog/tplog2024.06.05
It hasnt changed from when I ran it with two tables and it worked but now all of sudden it doesn't work

When you subscribe to the TP it should return the following
q)x
`quote +`time`sym`bid`ask`bsize`asize!(`timespan$();`g#`symbol$();`float$();`float$();`int$();`int$())
`trade +`time`sym`price`size!(`timespan$();`g#`symbol$();`float$();`int$())
q)x 0
`quote
+`time`sym`bid`ask`bsize`asize!(`timespan$();`g#`symbol$();`float$();`float$();`int$();`int$())
q)x 1
`trade
+`time`sym`price`size!(`timespan$();`g#`symbol$();`float$();`int$())
q)x[0;0]
`quote
q)x[0;1]
time sym bid ask bsize asize
----------------------------
q)x[1;0]
`trade
q)x[1;1]
time sym price size
-------------------

